# Bought refurbished PS4, can’t connect to either controller

Tags: ps4, controllers

(EDIT: I have found out what I was doing wrong! There was a spare USB cable that I didn’t see earlier, and that just so happened to be the one I needed to “jumpstart” my PS4! Thank you all so much for the help though, and hopefully in case someone else needs similar help to me, I’m keeping this up.)

I have very recently bought a refurbished PS4 for myself, and I’m sad to say I’m already having troubles before I can even play any kinds of games.

Neither of my PS4 controllers I bought with it connect to the thing. One was straight out of the box too. They’re both Sony brand as well, nothing third party.

I’ve tried resetting the controllers, turning off and on my PS4, even getting three other USB ports. Nothing. Just the same screen telling me to connect my DualShock 4 to the usb and press the button.

Sadly, since it’s factory reset, I’m not able to reach any kind of Home Screen, so no settings for another reset or even Bluetooth connection.
Is there anyway I can fix this? I only bought a PS4 because I wanted to play online with my boyfriend, who also owns a PS4, so I’m very very new to this system.

Comment: For the USB cables: Make sure they're data cables. Some USB cables are wired for power only and won't work for anything except charging.

Comment: And just to ask the dumb question: are you connecting the controller to the Console itself? The only other thing I can think of is you need to turn the console off, then turn it on with the connected controller.

Comment: @Magnus, if you resolved the issue, you can answer your own question. This will make it easier to find a solution for others that are having the same problem.